# How to make a boolean column from another column with condition

Tags: sql, oracle

**I have to reach the best performance!**

So, i have a table (my_table1) where are 3 columns: `ID`, `RID`(primary_key), `VALUE1`.
I want to make a new `boolean` column in another table (my_table2).

I decode-d my `VALUE1` column, so its output can be `1` or `NULL`.

```
 RID    |   ID   | VALUE1
--------|--------|--------
 132501 |  1001  |   1
 132501 |  1002  |   
 132501 |  1003  |   
 132501 |  1004  |   1
 132501 |  1005  |   
 132501 |  1006  |   1
```

If all values of `VALUE1` column is `1` i want to get `1`.
If **ANY** value of `VALUE1` column is `NULL` i want to get `0`.

In this specific case output be like - (my_table2):

```
 RID_2  |ID_TBL_2| NEW_BOOL_COL
--------|--------|--------
 132501 |  3214  |   0
```

What's the best way to solve this problem ?

Comment: How is the `ID` 3214 in the output while in the input it's from 1001 to 1006?

Comment: @rad it's another table (my_table2).

Comment: Couldn't you decode to 1 or 0, then you can do a `MIN(VALUE1) GROUP BY RID`?

Comment: Oracle does not support a booelan type for columns.  I think you just want some sort of number.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I am aware of it. I want a number, of course.. It's like a `boolean` -> 1 = true; 0 = false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an answer which aggregates `VALUE1` based on the `RID`:

```
SELECT
    RID,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(VALUE1) = COUNT(*) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NEW_BOOL_COL
FROM my_table1
GROUP BY RID;
```

You may easily enough use this logic in the context of joining to another table.

Answer (score 1):

There's no boolean column type for tables in Oracle. I think you're looking for an Integer.

You may use a correlated update with a `count` query from my_table1

```
update my_table2 t2 set NEW_BOOL_COL = 
( select 
  case when count( case when value1 = 1 then 1 end ) = 
    count(*) then 1 else 0 end 
from my_table1 t1 where t1.rid = t2.rid_2 
group by t1.rid
);
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ddd99539f0677ac56b8f7b5579838d3f)